# How to disable boot sound that comes while starting MacBook pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I have macbook pro mid 2012 edition. I want to disable sound at the time of boot that comes while turning on..

Comment: That has to be one of my favourite sounds...

Comment: not when you have an infant at home..

Comment: Well, I just put mine to sleep and avoid restarts unless absolutely necessary. and yes understand the kids issue...

Comment: @SolarMike nor when updating overnight.

Comment: @stevec set mine (4 different machines) to shut down at midnight and restart at 06.00 seems to work fine.